# PowerShell to find folder / file size

Tags: powershell, filesize

I am trying to write a script using powershell to get folder / file size as mentioned below

```cs
$StartFolder = "D:\"
$Output = "C:\Temp\test-d.csv"

Add-Content -Value "Folder Path|Size" -Path $Output

$colItems = (Get-ChildItem $startFolder -Recurse | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum)
"$StartFolder -- " + "{0:N2}" -f ($colItems.Sum / 1MB) + " MB" # | Out-File $Output

$colItems = (Get-ChildItem $startFolder -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True} | Sort-Object)
foreach ($i in $colItems) {
    $subFolderItems = (Get-ChildItem $i.FullName -Recurse | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum)
    $i.FullName + "|" + "{0:N2}" -f ($subFolderItems.Sum / 1MB) + " MB" | Out-File $Output -Append
}
```

I am getting error as mentioned below:

```
Measure-Object : The property "Length" cannot be found in the input for any
objects.
At line:12 char:65
+         $subFolderItems = (Get-ChildItem $i.FullName -Recurse | Measure-Object - ...
+
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Measure-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GenericMeasurePropertyNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MeasureObjectCommand

Measure-Object : The property "Length" cannot be found in the input for any
objects.
At line:12 char:65
+         $subFolderItems = (Get-ChildItem $i.FullName -Recurse | Measure-Object - ...
+
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Measure-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GenericMeasurePropertyNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MeasureObjectCommand
```

Also, when I target C: drive I am getting "access denied" on some system files:

```
Get-ChildItem : Access to the path 'C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\WMI\RtBackup'
is denied.
At line:12 char:28
+         $subFolderItems = (Get-ChildItem $i.FullName -Recurse | Measure-Object - ...
+                            
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Windows\Syst...es\WMI\RtBackup:String) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Comment: If you are not an admin or do not have privileges , you wont be able to modify system directories like that. So either you can try with run as admin or give necessary permissions.

since its not having access, it is not able to pick the length.

Comment: Why the hell are you concatenating table viewl with pipes like that? PowerShell has built in support for csv, json and there are modules for excel as well...

Answer (score 3):

[`DirectoryInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx) objects don't have a property `Length`, so you need to restrict your size calculation to files.

```
$colItems = Get-ChildItem $startFolder -Recurse -Force |
            Where-Object { -not $_.PSIsContainer } |
            Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum
```

It might be easier to use a `Scripting.FileSystemObject` COM object, because that will allow you to get directory objects with the size of their content. And you may want to use `Export-Csv` for exporting your data to a CSV. Use [calculated properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) for building the required objects.

```
$fso = New-Object -COM 'Scripting.FileSystemObject'

$folders = @($StartFolder)
$folders += Get-ChildItem $StartFolder -Recurse -Force |
            Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer } |
            Select-Object -Expand FullName

$folders |
    Select-Object @{n='Path';e={$_}}, @{n='Size';e={$fso.GetFolder($_).Size}} |
    Export-Csv $Output -Delimiter '|' -NoType
```

Comment: Slight syntax error in the     `select-object`.  Should be a comma instead of a semicolon separating the two items:    `Select-Object @{n='Path';e={$_}}, @{n='Size';e={$fso.GetFolder($_).Size}} |`

Comment: Indeed. Thanks for the heads up. Fixed.

Comment: @ Ansgar Wiechers & Itchydon, thanks for your reply and my apologies for delayed reply. I am also looking into get the size of the hidden files as well along with other files size...Is there a way we can do, can you pls let me know...

Comment: `Get-ChildItem -Force`

Comment: Tried both - 
`Get-ChildItem $StartFolder -Recurse -Force` & `Get-ChildItem -Force $StartFolder -Recurse`

Comment: got error as mentioned below - 

`Get-ChildItem : Access to the path 'C:\Users\.NET v4.5 Classic\Start Menu' is denied.`
`At line:6 char:13`
`+ $Folders = (Get-ChildItem $StartFolder -Recurse -Force | Measure-Object -propert ...`
`+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~`
`+ CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Users\.NET v4.5` `Classic\Start Menu:String) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId :` `DirUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand`

Comment: PowerShell can't traverse folders the user doesn't have access to. In your case the errors appear to be from [junctions that exist for compatibility reasons](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968829.aspx) (see [here](https://www.svrops.com/svrops/articles/jpoints.htm) for a more detailed explanation). Either ignore them (they don't interrupt processing anyway) or suppress the error messages by adding `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to `Get-ChildItem`.